# Proving Combinatorical Summation: $n!=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

been stuck with this question for the last few hours, any help would be appreciated.

$$
{\large n! = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{k}{\,n\, \choose \,k\,}
\left(\,n - k\,\right)^{n}}
$$

what I did:

$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k(n-k)^n}{k!(n-k)!}.$

So we are left to prove $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k(n-k)^n}{k!(n-k)!}=1$. tried doing so using induction, or treating the sum as geometric sequence (which turned out poorly)

Suggestions?

Comment: I have seen this before in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%B6rlund%E2%80%93Rice_integral). Combining this with the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413600/show-that-the-kth-forward-difference-of-xn-is-divisible-by-k) is what you want.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591350/factorial-as-difference-of-powers) is a clearer answer of the same question.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/697506/115115

Answer (score 3):

For $j\lt n$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{m+k}{j}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{m}{j-i}\binom{k}{i}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{m}{j-i}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{m}{j-i}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{k-i}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{m}{j-i}\binom{n}{i}(-1)^i\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k-i}\binom{n-i}{k-i}\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^j\binom{m}{j-i}\binom{n}{i}(-1)^i0^{n-i}\tag{5}\\[9pt]
&=0\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: [Vandermonde Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(2)$: rearrange terms
$(3)$: $\binom{n\vphantom{k}}{k}\!\!\binom{k}{i}=\binom{n\vphantom{k}}{i}\!\!\binom{n-i}{k-i}$ by expansion into factorials
$(4)$: rearrange terms
$(5)$: binomial expansion of $(1-1)^{n-i}$
$(6)$: all terms in the sum are zero

Any polynomial in $m$ of degree less than $n$ can be written as a linear combination of $\binom{m}{j}$ for $j\lt n$. Therefore, if $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than $n$, then $(6)$ says that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}P(m+k)=0\tag{7}
$$
Since $\color{#C00000}{k^n-n!\binom{k}{n}}$ is a polynomial in $k$ of degree less than $n$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\color{#C00000}{k^n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\color{#C00000}{n!\binom{k}{n}}\\
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n}\\[9pt]
&=n!\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
since the only term in the last sum that is not zero is when $k=n$.

Comment: Upon reading the comments to the question, I see that I wrote [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/591717). Duplication of effort; oh well.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{n! = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}\pars{n - k}^{n}}$

> \begin{align}
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}\pars{n - k}^{n}
> &=n!\bracks{\overbrace{\color{#c00000}{%
> {1 \over n!}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}\pars{n - k}^{n}}}
> ^{\ds{{\rm S}\pars{n,n} = 1}}}
> \end{align}
>   The $\color{#c00000}{\ds{\mbox{above red expression}}}$ is the
>   [Stirling Number of the Second Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html)
>   $\ds{{\rm S}\pars{n,n}}$. See formula $\pars{10}$ in the just cited link.

$\ds{{\rm S}\pars{n,n}}$ is the number of ways of partitioning a set of $\ds{n}$ elements into $\ds{n}$ nonempty sets which is obviously $\large\tt\mbox{equal to one}$.

> $$\color{#66f}{\large%
> n! = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}\pars{n - k}^{n}}
> $$

Answer (score 0):

If $(Δp)(x)=p(x)−p(x-1)$ denotes the step-one difference operator, one gets by repeated application
$$
(Δ^np)(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k} p(x-k)
$$
and your expression is equal to
$$
n!=(Δ^np)(n)
$$
where $p(x)=x^n$.

Now in general, the degree decreases by one in each application of the difference operator, $\deg(Δ^np)=\deg(p)-n$, so that by starting with $\deg p=n$ the result is a constant which only depends on the leading coefficient of $p$. Since 
$$
Δ(x^m)=x^m-(x-1)^m=mx^{m-1}-\binom{m}2 x^{m-1}+...
$$
the leading coefficient of $Δ^kp$ is $p_n\cdot n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$ and thus the leading coefficient of $Δ^np$ is $n!\cdot p_n$.

Answer (score 0):

First, ask yourself the following question: $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^na^k{n\choose k}x^{n-k}~=~?\quad$ *Hint:* See [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Then apply the following two steps repeatedly: $(1).$ Differentiate both sides with respect to *x*, and

$(2).$ Multiply both sides with *x*. Notice how, after each two steps, $\bigg(x\dfrac d{dx}\bigg)^k\circ(x-1)^n$ can be

rewritten as $(x-1)^{n-k}\cdot P_k(x)$, where $P_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree *k* in *x* and *n*. Notice also

that $P_k(1)=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$. Try to prove these two observations by induction. Then it

is quite evident that $P_n(1)$ will be $n!$